# Kubernetest: The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

Tags: kubernetes

I have followed the guide https://www.server-world.info/query?os=CentOS_7&p=kubernetes&f=1 for kubernetes configuration. When i run the command "kubectl version -o json"
The subject error comes.

Comment: Please follow [kubectl instalation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#install-kubectl-on-linux)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This usually means that either Minikube was unable to start or you have something wonky with your networking. Both require detailed debugging and are probably out of scope for a SO question since there is no single cause.